# Fill in the operators to make $7 \circ 8 \circ 7 \circ 7 \circ 8 \circ 3 = 100$

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, formation-of-numbers

With the given numbers I need to make:

> $7 \circ 8 \circ 7 \circ 7 \circ 8 \circ 3 = 100$

Using only the following operators:

> $+\space-\space\times\space\div$

Answer (score 7):

> $7 \times 8 + 7 \times 7 - 8 + 3 = 100$

Comment: This is pretty much it if we can't use parenthesis.. +1

Answer (score 0):

General "Countdown" arithmetic puzzle solution !!

Some Unix Shells have a property called 'brace expansion'

The usage varies between **csh** and **bash** but is something like this:

```
echo {a,i}{s,t}
```

Outputs:

```
as at is it
```

This can be used to solve the "Countdown" letters puzzle, simply have 9 consecutive braces with all 9 letters in each.  If you don't know Countdown, you can use this to find Scrabble™ words, if you add a final brace at the end like **{'\n'}** you even get one result per line so you can pipe output through **sort** or **usr/dict**

So how do we do the Arithmetic puzzle ?

If we are given the integers 2,4,5

Alternate braces containing integers and operators:

```
set array {2,4,5}{+,-,\*,/}{2,4,5}…{'\n'} # * escaped to avoid wildcard
```

This gives:

```
2+2-4…
2-3*4…
```

Every permutation of integer and operator.  Finally,

```
foreach s in (array) {echo $s ; eval $s} | sort
```

Evaluates all the expressions and even sorts them so you can find the **integer you are looking for** and the expression which created it.

"Countdown"™ Solved !!!